# htaccess redirect issue

Tags: .htaccess

The redirect only works on mac..?

```
AddHandler php5-script .php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Test at [tipfortip.com](http://tipfortip.com)

Comment: It is not clear from your question what problem you are trying to solve. When I click on your test link, I get redirected to `https://www.tipfortip.com` and I am not on a mac. (In fact, the OS of the client machine accessing the site is irrelevant.) Are you saying that this rewrite works on a non-Mac server, but not on a mac server? Also, you do not need to repeat the `RewriteEngine On`--you only need that once.

Comment: Oh interesting, it works now and I didn't change anything! lol

Comment: @RobertB, if you'd like post that as an answer and I'll choose it.

Comment: Maybe you restarted the server? :)

Comment: Could that really change something like htaccess effectiveness?

Comment: Hmmm... no, I guess a reboot shouldn't affect .htaccess. <shrug />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear from your question what problem you are trying to solve. When I click on your test link, I get redirected to https://www.tipfortip.com and I am not on a mac. (In fact, the OS of the client machine accessing the site is irrelevant.) Are you saying that this rewrite works on a non-Mac server, but not on a mac server? Also, you do not need to repeat the RewriteEngine On--you only need that once.